# using "Reference3 Interface" to add desired references to a project

Tags: c#

I found this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj80.reference3%28VS.80%29.aspx

what I have in mind is that many of the references that we add to our project are on a network drive and there are TON of them. Adding references to the project by right clicking on the References in the porject and choosing add reference is a pain.

so I was wondering if I can take advantage of something like what I posted the link to it and have a small program,add-in,macro, etc! that we can give it a list of the references that I want and it will add them to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't vouch for the Reference3 interface, but you might get some mileage out of the [PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2008](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands) project.

This project demonstrates Visual Studio extensibility. The PowerCommands include a context menu option on project references to copy and paste references between projects, or to copy a project as a project reference and paste within another.

If it's worth your time to get familiar with the code, you should have a good idea of how to manipulate project references, and be able to integrate your custom logic right into Visual Studio.

I hope this helps.